# End two nodes on single node in family tree

Tags: html, css

I want to end two nodes on a single node in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uPdZX

Html Code:

```
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

this is the code ...what i want to do is to end both grand child on a single great grand child...how to achieve this ...what should i do ...any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: just for your information: http://astuteo.com/slickmap

Answer (score 0):

They will be on the same level if you remove the following CSS3 statement (or set the padding to 20px):

```
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
```

Still, you will need to ad an extra vertical connector (if needed).

Comment: i don't want to remove it ...i just want to do it when a specific condition gets true then two nodes should end on one node

Comment: Sorry, I probably misinterpret your original requirements. For more complex conditions try to apply jQuery rather that pure CSS.